# multiplication of doubles variables

Tags: multiplication, date-arithmetic

a question i saw and didn't quite understand.

first we create arbitrary values:

```
int x = random();
int y = random();
int z = random();
```

(int is 32 bits)
then continue with:

```
double dx = (double) x;
double dy = (double) y;
double dz = (double) z;
```

(double is 64 bits)

the question was to tell if the next statements are **always** true (returns 1) or not.

```
a. dx+dy+dz==dz+dy+dx

b. dx*dy*dz==dz*dy*dx
```

the answer to (a) was "yes, Within range of exact representation by double's"
(so, is it or is it not *always* true? and if it is not *always* true, I would like an example of 3 values for dx, dy, dz which returns 0)

the answer to (b) was "no, e.g dx=Tmax, dy=Tmax-1, dz=Tmax-2"
i tried and it turned out to be the same result (but most likely i'm was wrong :-/ )

I would like to understand why those answers are correct

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In floating point arithmetic, you should **never** test for equality. A classic example is `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. (See http://0.30000000000000004.com/ for more information, particularly to see if your language hides this from you. It has a nice explanation of how this arises because 0.1 and 0.3 can't be exactly represented in doubles.) Floating-point values should instead be checked to see if they're close enough to each other in a certain range, usually called "tolerance".

See the IEEE 754 definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

I disagree with the answer to (a), because it's meaningless to specify what can be "exactly represented" by a double - if every input is the double representation of the given random bits (x, y, z), then it is, by definition that exact representation. Plus, it's dubious to say "yes, but only under some conditions" as an answer to "is this **always** true?" The answer in that case is "no".

One counterexample to (a) is below. I constructed this by considering that floating point numbers have only a certain relative precision, so adding a very small number to a very large one may make no difference. Make that small number large enough, and it will.

- `1e16 + 1 + 1 = 10000000000000000`
- `1 + 1 + 1e16 = 10000000000000002`

As for (b), the first thing I randomly tried was a counterexample:

- `0.1 * 0.1 * 0.7 = 0.007000000000000001`
- `0.7 * 0.1 * 0.1 = 0.006999999999999999`